# Why does the feature_block.py bitcoin functional test fail in tagged release 0.16.0?

Tags: bitcoin-core, testing

I tried running the unit and functional tests from the latest tagged release (0.16.0) from https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin.git.

To my surprise, there is one functional test that persistently fails for me (everything else passes).  I'm running on a VirtualBox'd Ubuntu guest (host is OS X if it matters).

Any idea what might be wrong?  Is it truly failed functionality or did I just run the test incorrectly?  If the former, what is its significance to the correctness of the latest bitcoin?

```
2018-03-19 18:03:57.574000 TestFramework.comptool (INFO): Running test 97: ./feature_block.py line 1279
2018-03-19 18:05:00.534000 TestFramework (ERROR): Assertion failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jack/projects/bitcoin-audit/bitcoin/test/functional/test_framework/test_framework.py", line 123, in main
    self.run_test()
  File "./feature_block.py", line 76, in run_test
    self.test.run()
  File "/home/jack/projects/bitcoin-audit/bitcoin/test/functional/test_framework/comptool.py", line 341, in run
    self.sync_blocks(block.sha256, 1)
  File "/home/jack/projects/bitcoin-audit/bitcoin/test/functional/test_framework/comptool.py", line 211, in sync_blocks
    self.wait_for_pings(self.ping_counter)
  File "/home/jack/projects/bitcoin-audit/bitcoin/test/functional/test_framework/comptool.py", line 191, in wait_for_pings
    wait_until(received_pongs, lock=mininode_lock)
  File "/home/jack/projects/bitcoin-audit/bitcoin/test/functional/test_framework/util.py", line 222, in wait_until
    assert_greater_than(timeout, time.time())
  File "/home/jack/projects/bitcoin-audit/bitcoin/test/functional/test_framework/util.py", line 42, in assert_greater_than
    raise AssertionError("%s <= %s" % (str(thing1), str(thing2)))
AssertionError: 1521482700.509922 <= 1521482700.533904
2018-03-19 18:05:00.547000 TestFramework (INFO): Stopping nodes
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jack/projects/bitcoin-audit/bitcoin/test/functional/test_framework/authproxy.py", line 106, in _request
    self.__conn.request(method, path, postdata, headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1239, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1285, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1234, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1065, in _send_output
    self.send(chunk)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 986, in send
    self.sock.sendall(data)
BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```